Data is not showing correspondently on flutter app after retrieve from firestore
When 'selectedNumbers', 'fRAmount', 'sRAmount' is retrieved from Firestore its not showing correspondently. I attached screenshot how its showing before saved to Firestore and after retrieve. I alos attached screenshot of Firestore.

Screenshot Before Save to Firestore on Flutter paymentScreen class - Before saving to firestore screenshot

After Retrieve From Firestore on Flutter paymentReponseHanlder class -After retrieve from firestore screenshot

Firestore Screenshot - Firestore screenshot


Save to Firestore from Paymenscreen class-
 
Future<void> createOrderAndInitiatePayment(BuildContext context) async {
   
    
    List<String?> cleanedFRAmounts = fRAmounts
        .where((amount) => amount != null && amount.isNotEmpty)
        .toList();
    List<String?> cleanedSRAmounts = sRAmounts
        .where((amount) => amount != null && amount.isNotEmpty)
        .toList();


    //order data
    final orderData = {
      "selected_numbers":
          selectedNumbers.map((number) => number.toString()).toList(),
      "f_r_amounts": cleanedFRAmounts,
      "s_r_amounts": cleanedSRAmounts,
    };


    // Save to Firestore
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('orders')
          .doc(orderId)
          .set(orderData);
      print('Order saved to Firestore');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error saving order to Firestore: $e');
    }



//selectedNumbers, fRAmount, sRAmount saved UI on paymentScreen class

       ...selectedNumbers.map((number) {
            String? frAmount = number < fRAmounts.length
                ? fRAmounts[number]
                : null;
            String? srAmount = number < sRAmounts.length
                ? sRAmounts[number]
                : null;
            return ListTile(
              title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        number.toString(), // Convert int to String
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        (frAmount != null) ? '₹$frAmount' : '×',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        (srAmount != null) ? '₹$srAmount' : '×',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),


After Retrieve on payementResponseHandler -
final selectedNumbers = List<int>.from(
            (data['selected_numbers'] as List)
                .map((e) => int.parse(e.toString())));
final fRAmounts = List<String?>.from(data['f_r_amounts']);
final sRAmounts = List<String?>.from(data['s_r_amounts']);


// UI  of selectedNumebers, framount, sramount on paymentresponsehandler


 ...selectedNumbers.map((number) {
    int index = selectedNumbers.indexOf(number);
    String? frAmount = index < fRAmounts.length
        ? fRAmounts[index]
        : null;
    String? srAmount = index < sRAmounts.length
        ? sRAmounts[index]
        : null;

    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment:
            MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                number.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                (frAmount != null) ? '₹$frAmount' : '×',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                (srAmount != null) ? '₹$srAmount' : '×',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }),


Data should be show same as it is,  before saving and after retrieve.
